# How do you know when a textfield is edited in Flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, keyboard, textfield

Does the textfield send events when its edited, or scrolled by the user?

What about key presses when focus is on the textfield? do you get those?

Comment: Just adding a stock QnA to answer this basic yet hard-to-put-together answer. Notice how all of the important events (change, keypress, scroll) are NOT stored in the TextEvent class. Wierd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Textfields send many useful events:

- When modified by the user -- Event.CHANGE
- When text is typed into it -- TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT
- When a link is clicked -- TextEvent.LINK
- When scrolled by the user -- Event.SCROLL
- When a key is pressed -- KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN -- (only fires while editing a textfield)

You can easily listen for keyboard events occurring when the textfield is focused.

Just add a KEY_DOWN event directly to the textfield, and then do whatever you want.

```
// get key presses only when the textfield is being edited
inputText.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);
function handler(event:KeyboardEvent){

   // if the key is ENTER
   if(event.charCode == 13){

       // your code here
       doSomething();
   }
}
```